# Canada - Can I make an in-kind transfer to avoid paying capital gains?

Tags: canada, capital-gains-tax, transfer

I am planning on paying my girlfriend back 18K, which she plans on putting in her RRSP. Rather than sell funds that are in my non-registered investment account (which would cause me to pay capital gains) I was hoping to make an in-kind transfer of the shares to her, which she could then put in her RRSP directly. Am I allowed to do this? It seems like this would allow people to avoid paying capital gains taxes whcih I'm sure the government doesn't allow. What am I missing, who is charged the capital gains and when?

Comment: Not an answer because I'm only familiar with US laws, but in the US, the cost basis transfers over to whoever is receiving the shares. So when they sell, they'd pay the full capital gains tax on the full cost basis from when you acquired the shares.

Comment: Marriage soon? `You generally do not have a capital gain or loss if you give capital property to your spouse or common-law partner`  https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/forms-publications/publications/t4037/capital-gains.html#P2164_103916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to pay capital gains tax.  Here is a document explaining all the different scenarios.

https://ca.rbcwealthmanagement.com/documents/720599/720615/Tax+Treatment+of+In-Kind+Asset+Transfers+-+use+this.pdf

> Transfer made to arm’s length individuals.
> Arm’s length individuals
> generally include individuals who are not related to you and who act
> independently from you. At the time of the transfer The transfer of
> assets is a taxable transaction; you dispose of your assets to the
> arm’s length person at fair market value. You report the capital gain
> or loss realized on the disposition on your income tax return. The ACB
> of the transferred assets is the fair market value of the assets on
> the date of transfer.