# Can I transfer stocks from a margin account to a TFSA to avoid capital gains tax?

Tags: investing, canada, capital-gains-tax, tfsa

I am new to trading and ended up opening a margin account rather than a TFSA a few months ago. I know I can sell my stock and then buy it again in the TFSA, but the stock price has gone up and I am afraid I have to pay a lot of tax! :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are going to have to pay tax on the increase in value between when you bought it and when you transfer it to the TFSA.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/a/136583/13241 , read the linked document pg 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though no actual sale and repurchase is done, it is considered a sale in the margin account and a purchase in the TFSA for income tax purposes (i.e. Capital Gains)